# How can i generate vibration according to a binary pattern using Android studio?

Tags: android

I'm a android self learner. I want to generate vibration for binary string.
Here is the code I used

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnVibrate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsum);


    // Set on click listener and start vibrate service when clicked on      Button Vibrate

    btnVibrate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Create a New Intent and start the service
            Intent intentVibrate =new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),VIBRATOR_SERVICE.getClass());
            startService(intentVibrate);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
I want to generate vibration according to a binary string.If i give like '110' a particular vibration should generate for that string..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string into an array

```
char[] charPattern = yourString.toCharArray();
```

Then convert your char array into a long array:

```
long[] pattern = new long[charPattern.length];
for (int i = 0; i < charPattern.length; i++) {
    long[i] = char[i] = Long.valueOf(char[i])
}
```

And use your array in the vibrator.

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(pattern, 1);
```

Comment: long[] pattern = long[chars.length];                                                                   This statement shows me an error............

Comment: You have to initiate the pattern array with the same lenght as charPattern so : ong[] pattern = long[charPattern.length];

Comment: long[] pattern =Long[charPattern.length];                                                      still shows an error to me .Plz help...

Comment: If you want to initialize your array with a length of 5: long[] pattern = new long[5];  Here we want to initliaze it with the length of charPatterne, so  long[] pattern = new long[charPattern.length];